# Count binary tree left and right children separately

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

I have this code that counts only the number of right children of a binary tree.

```
int count(Arbin<T> a){

if(a.isEmpty()) return 0;

int num_l=0, num_r=0;
if(!a.leftChild.isEmpty()) 
    num_l = count(a.leftChild());
if(!a.rightChild.isEmpty()) 
    num_r = count(a.rightChild())+1;

return num_l+num_r;}
```

How can I modify it so I can get the number of right children and the number of left children separately?

`Arbin` class only allow me to do this operations (and I can not modify it):

- `rightChild()`: returns the node of the right child
- `leftChild()`: returns the node of the left child
- `isEmpty()`: returns whether the node is empty or not

Comment: You are getting them "separately". You count the left and than the right.

Comment: As written, you would always get a count of 0... as 0 + 0 is equal to 0. Draw a binary tree on paper, mark the node you want to count with a pencil and it should be trivial to implement count. By the way 90% of the code is already done.

Comment: Yes but I want to calculate them **for each sub-tree** until it reaches the parent. The problem is that if I use a global variable, the values are only valid for the whole tree and not for each specific sub-tree

Comment: `count(a.rightChild()+1)` -> `count(a.rightChild())+1`?

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify `count()` then do the following:

```
void count(Arbin<T> a, int& l, int& r){

if(a.isEmpty()) return ;

if(!a.leftChild.isEmpty()) 
    count(a.leftChild(), l+1, r);
if(!a.rightChild.isEmpty()) 
    count(a.rightChild(), l, r+1);

}
```

Now call `count` as following

```
int l = 0, r = 0;
count(tree, l, r);
// here you've left child count in `l` and right count in `r`
```